# What is the most stable method to make linux kernel headers/devel a requirement for RPMs and Debs?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, apt, deb

I'm looking for the "best"* method to add the linux kernel headers and development libraries as a requirement for an RPM and Debian package I'm making. I know that I can add a "Requires: blah" tag in the RPM .spec file, and that I can do the analog in the Debian control file, but this will have the user download the latest kernel's headers/devel...not their current headers/devel.

For example, say the user is running linux kernel version 3.4, and the latest is 3.5. If they install the RPM via yum, and don't have any kernel headers or development libraries, they will download the 3.5 headers and development libraries. But when the software goes to build, it will try to find the 3.4 headers and development libraries and fail.

Thanks!

Comment: could you talk about your motiviation a bit more

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to install a kernel module using RPMs/Debs, and would like the module to link against headers for whichever kernel the user is using.

That way they don't have to be using the latest kernel to guarantee the headers/devel are installed.

Comment: At least in Debian, the kernel headers are versioned with precisely this sort of dependency, so the user gets the headers of the installed kernel rather than some arbirtary version.

Answer (score 0):

Debian at least easily allows you to specify a particular version in `Build-Depends:`. Usually you don't want to, but it's perfectly possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to avoid specifying the version at build time. If there was a way to have it require the headers for kernel $(uname -r), that'd be perfect.

Comment: That's what the user gets with an unversioned dependency. Or if you mean *your* kernel's bersion at packaging time, generate when you build, but then you wouldn't be saying you don't want to set at build time, would you?

Comment: I had thought that if a required package was not installed, yum/apt would download the latest. If it's smart enough to customize this logic for kernel related packages, that's awesome and I need to see if rpm does the same!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why something like this would not suffice (something like a minumum kernel required)

```
Requires: kernel >= 3.5
BuildRequires: kernel-headers >= 3.5
```

Comment: I don't want/need to restrict the kernel the user uses. Rather, I just need the appropriate headers to be installed when the user goes to install.

Comment: I am sorry if I miss the point, but what is the reason you require newer kernel headers? If your binary requires the newer kernel headers, then it probably requires a newer kernel too - if not, then you should allow the usage of older kernel headers too. To me, this seems to be rather a limitation of the software you package than a issue with the package management - correct me if I am wrong. From the package-managments POV you would have to package the appropriate kernel yourself and supply it as an upgrade. Or as a hack, supply them with the package directly (not really encouraging that).

Comment: I think his problem is in specifying headers dependency for *current* kernel. When you say "kernel-headers" package manager might pull newer than what is installed, while you want matching ones.

Comment: If it really requires some specific headers as he stated, then it should be `Requires: kernel-headers = 3.4` though imho the sw should rather be fixed. This does not sound like something sane to do.

Comment: It might be possible to be using some stable API that are the same across most kernel versions you care about, but still require headers for the _current running kernel_, not some newest kernel available in the repo. Lots of kernel modules have this requirement. I don't think that is possible though, not without running a separate script to detect distro and running kernel and apply some heuristics to grab appropriate package using appropriate means. (because of course they name them differently in various distros, not to mention all the package management options...).

Comment: deb/rpm packages are almost always distro specific. I suggest you you create a package for each distro you want to support rather than jumping from issue to crazy and partly unresolveable issue(s). It's not worth your time.
For the headers issue, did you test what happens if you just do ’Require: kernel-headers’ with a newer kernel in the remote repository than you got installed? (Just grab a livecd or something, plug an usbstick with your custom package and just try installing, and see what happens if you try to install your package)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are trying to build/package some 3rd party kernel modules (since afaik this is really the only type of package that should depend on kernel-headers).

if so, you probably want to have a look at how other kernel-modules are packaged, esp, check [dkms](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/), which is supported by all major distributions, and use that to build your kernel module.